# Java .xml creating a drawable button background

Tags: java, android, xml, drawable, layer-list

New to programming, 3 weeks beginner.
I am making a button with stacked rectangles through drawable xml.

This is my button .xml code, very straight forward:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#D5A04F"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/leftnavbar"
            android:layout_width="212dp"
            android:layout_height="279dp"

            android:layout_marginTop="16sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="500sp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle"
             />
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this is my drawable .xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/mr_dialog_fixed_width_minor"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/mr_dialog_fixed_width_major"
    >

    <item
        android:top="5sp"
        android:left="5sp"
        android:right="5sp"
        android:bottom="50sp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#D3AE71" />
            <corners android:radius="20sp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>


    <item
        android:top="30sp"
        android:left="30sp"
        android:right="30sp"
        android:bottom="600sp">s
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#E6E5E5" />
                <corners android:radius="20sp"/>
            </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:top="160sp"
        android:left="30sp"
        android:right="30sp"
        android:bottom="470sp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#E6E5E5" />
            <corners android:radius="20sp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:top="290sp"
        android:left="30sp"
        android:right="30sp"
        android:bottom="340sp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#E6E5E5" />
            <corners android:radius="20sp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:top="420sp"
        android:left="30sp"
        android:right="30sp"
        android:bottom="210sp"
        >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#E6E5E5" />
            <corners android:radius="20sp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:top="550sp"
        android:left="30sp"
        android:right="30sp"
        android:bottom="80sp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#E6E5E5" />
            <corners android:radius="20sp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The only item that is shown in drawable is the first, the rest of the rectangles fail to show.
Suggestions or pointers to the reason will be much apreciated. thank you for your time and attention...

Answer (score 0):

First of all please do not use "sp" for things other than text font size.

Second, pls look into excessive size of your `android:bottom`, like `600sp` for example - they are leaving no space for respective shapes.

Answer (score 0):

Your button's height is too short,chang android:layout_height="279dp" to  android:layout_height="700dp"

Comment: i noticed that expanding the button i am making the drawable for, started showing the drawable except its relative to the original drawable height and width size (which i am unable to change so far) that was the reason its not showing. i used a    ".png" instead and it worked...The Question remains how to set the "Drawable" dimensions properly for it to appear in proper size on the Button in question.